# How to remove small island patches in bitmap image masks using python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am new to image processing and is working on a project where I need to separate the images of the leaf form the background as a part of the project. I was able to create a mask using OpenCV but there are some patches that should be removed.

You can see the image below to get a clear understanding of what I meant:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

input = cv2.imread('source.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(input, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#find all contours
img = cv2.pyrDown(gray)
_, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours,_ = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#find maximum contour and draw   
cmax = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea) 
epsilon = 0.002 * cv2.arcLength(cmax, True)
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cmax, epsilon, True)
cv2.drawContours(input, [approx], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

cv2.imshow("Contour", input)

width, height = gray.shape

#fill maximum contour and draw   
img = np.zeros( [width, height, 3],dtype=np.uint8 )
cv2.fillPoly(img, pts =[cmax], color=(255,255,255))

cv2.imshow("Filtered", img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Algorithm**:

1. [FindContours](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) method. You can adjust epsilon parameter.
2. Take maximum countur - this is your leaf.
3. Fill this maximum countur and draw it. Now you can smooth it or perform any other morphological operation.

**Results**:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On this [page](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) of the documentation, use [opening](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#opening) for your little points, and [Morphological gradient](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#morphological-gradient) to fill the middle of your image.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I tried using opening and morphological gradient. Resulted in this : [link](https://imgur.com/a/PMyZo4p)

Comment: @AroopNanda I cannot know for you the parameters of these functions. You should try and play with them, for instance, you can set `iterations=1` and see what happens. You must have other parameters, but then, I cannot know what to do at your place.